# Use high definition tab bar icons programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uitabbar

I was wondering how I should go about using high definition tab bar icons if my tab bar icons are being set programmatically.  I'm pretty much just doing the standard:

```
tabBarItem2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ExploreIcon.png"];
```

Will putting two images in my supporting files named "ExploreIcon.png" at 30x30 pixels and "ExploreIcon@2x.png" work without using additional code?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not consider choosing file which fits and displays better on a specified device, Let iOS do that for you.
Just keep files to support all possible devices.

**Follow:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

```
tabBarItem2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ExploreIcon.png"];
```

This is good enough. Just make sure the file names are appropriate. i.e.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for including the sizes!

Comment: I would change your size back to the 114 x 114 and 57 x 57 for future people who see this, it looks better at those sizes in my opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the retina version, the system will use the higher resolution version if present in the bundle. Also you don't need to add the extension

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"ExploreIcon"];
```

the two images should have te same name for example :

```
ExploreIcon.png
ExploreIcon@2x.png
```

Comment: Does it matter what the higher resolution image is named?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add an imageview and set the cgrect size 40*40 and than you will add that image view on the tab bar icon image.

Comment: My bad, I though you were saying to drag a uiimageview in, I was reading too quickly.  And are you sure I have to use an image view?  It's working just doing tabBarItem5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfileIcon.png"];

Comment: yes in most cases if you are putting larger image on to the small container  we need to render that image so we need an imageview to set and render that image . after that you can add that image view on to the tab bar image

Comment: Okay that makes sense!  And I tried it the other way and it appears to be working, but I'll keep your way in mind for future image related problems!